# Convert a value with 2 places after decimal to 6 places after decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to convert a value with 2 places after decimal to 6 places after decimal in MSSQL?

Eg : 350.00 to 350.000000

```
SELECT ROUND(350.00, 6) AS RoundValue;
```

Returns 350.00

Expected output is 350.000000

Should a function other than `round()` be used?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe cast to a decimal with the number of places you want ? `Cast(@Var as decimal( num_of_digits, decimal_places ))`

Comment: And how would that work given that decimal, like any number in any programming language, does not record a format?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean... The comment I gave above, gives the output OP wanted

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Sounds like a job for your presentation layer, not your database layer

Comment: Not sure why you would think round would do that.

Comment: No matter how many decimals there are, the *client* won't respect them when it converts the `numeric` bytes to text. `numeric` is a binary type, the same as `int` or `float`. That's another reason why you should do formatting on the client. It's also a lot faster, easier to maintain and the client *knows* which decimal separator to use. That `350.000000` could be formatted into `350M` in [half the world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator#/media/File:DecimalSeparator.svg). It would be "most of the world" if it wasn't for China and India

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - that very much depends on the client. SSMS is an example of a client which does show as many digits after the decimal point as the Scale. As is DB Fiddle seemingly https://dbfiddle.uk/TisWybJ9

Comment: Those are edge cases that actually validate the rule - both are DBA tools that explicitly work with the metadata returned by ODBC/OLEDB. Once you map to client types like `decimal` or `double` though in most (if not all) programming languages, that metadata is lost.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - yeah, true

Answer (score 0):

You do not. There are no trailing zeroes on a NUMBER - only on a STRING.

Means: As long as you have the value in a number variable (in any programming language btw.) it will not record how many irrelevant zeroes there are - if you want to see them, you do that on the output and format the string.

SQL Server supports this - you need to convert the number into a string with the proper formatting.

This is not ROUND, this is FORMAT, in SQL Server. The output of that is not a number, by type, but a string - otherwise it would not maintain formatting. Bad for maths, good for output.

Comment: Just to note, `Format()` is quite expensive. On large datasets, you will notice a big difference, thus you should probably be formatting your data when presenting it, not when querying.